# Linked Content doesn't work for resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

So in our Styles.xaml doc we use an external xml to provide the colors for the styles. We thought this would provide a good level of abstractions to allow people who weren't coders to modify the look of our app.

It works something this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CalManv4UI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
 mc:Ignorable="d"
 >

  <XmlDataProvider x:Key="BrandInfo" Source="/Config/BrandInfo.xml" XPath="BrandRoot" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource BrandInfo}, XPath=//Colors/@TextBoxForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource BrandInfo}, XPath=//Colors/@TextBoxBackground}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
 </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And this works and all is well, but we needed to add a couple of helper apps that would reuse the style of the main app.

So I was referencing the main app so that I can get to all the code goo, and then also reuse the styles.  But when I do this I get an IOException "Cannot locate resource 'config/brandinfo.xml'.".  I double checked that the brandinfo.xml is being copied over since the mainApp is refrenced, so I was puzzled.

The next thing I thought I'd try is using it as a linked file, so I created a config folder and added as link, set it to content copy always. Which creates this code in my csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Content Include="..\MainAppUI\Config\BrandInfo.xml">
  <Link>Config\BrandInfo.xml</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Still doesn't work, so finially I added it as a file. Which creates this code in my csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Content Include="Config\BrandInfo.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

So this works, but now I have two copies of my BrandInfo file, which could be a problem for matienance going forward.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Luckily, [this](http://learnwpf.com/post/2008/11/15/XAML-Complier-has-issues-with-linked-xaml-files.aspx) had a clue in it - the linked file is in the root.

So, lets say I have the following structure:
MyAssembly -> MyFolder -> MyDictionary.xaml

To load the dictionary form App.xaml do:

1. if MyDictionary.xaml is a "real" file -

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <ReosurceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/MyFolder/MyDictionary.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
2. if MyDictionary.xaml is a linked file -

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <ReosurceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/MyDictionary.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

(NOTE: MyFolder is ommited)

Warning: I tested the code on a machine not connected to the internet and the snippets are written in Notepad++ so spelling or syntax may be off.

Comment: This seems to address including XAML files from external assemblies, but I'm dealing with loose xml files.

Comment: Try to use `pack://sourceoforigin:` syntax, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: I encountered the same issue when sharing files between Silverlight and WPF. I fixed it by moving the original files to WPF and using the linked ones in the Silverlight solution. The compiler for Silverlight seems to work correctly with linked files! (I fixed the link for you) http://learnwpf.com/post/2008/11/15/XAML-Complier-has-issues-with-linked-xaml-files.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to find walkaround for this issue. What problem have we got? The problem is that in Design Mode Uri

```
"/UBP.Documents.RWS;component/Resources/ThirdPartyDocumentResourceDictionary.xaml"
```

is correct

but in the runtime we must substitute it for

```
"/UBP.Documents.RWS;component/ThirdPartyDocumentResourceDictionary.xaml"
```

Is it possible to do this automatically? And that is I'm thinking of: 
I want to make MyResourceDictionary class inherited from standard ResourceDictionary and make substitutions based on whether we are in DesignTime or not.

Rough code looks like:

```
 public class MyResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
    {

        new public Uri Source
        {
            get 
            {
                return base.Source;                
            }
            set
            {
                if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
                {
                    base.Source = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    string originalString = value.OriginalString;
                    string newString = originalString.Substring(0, originalString.IndexOf(";component") + 11) + originalString.Substring(originalString.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);                    
                    base.Source = new Uri(newString, UriKind.Relative);
                    base.Source = value;
                }                
            }
        }       
    }
```

Xaml looks like

```
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <localconverters:MyResourceDictionary Source="/UBP.Documents.RWS;component/Resources/ThirdPartyDocumentResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

and in runtime it works, but not in design mode (((
The next i fugured out while Debugging Design mode that in setter on line

```
base.Source = value;
```

exception occurs, it says "The URI prefix is not recognized."

I'm curious what's in my "value":

```
"markup://1/file:///D:/Svn/2.08.0016_20121116/Development/Sources/Universal/UBP.Documents.RWS/Presentation/ProbateCaseView.xaml%230//UBP.Documents.RWS;component/Resources/ThirdPartyDocumentResourceDictionary.xaml}".
```

It is not what I'm supposed to see (may be because of my rudimentary knowledge of Uri class).

I see except of my path to Resource dictionary ("/UBP.Documents.RWS;component/Resources/ThirdPartyDocumentResourceDictionary.xaml") there is a prefix with path to XAML file of my application, where this line ith written.
Could anyone explain me how to convert this Uri to my relative Uri, based on string

```
"/UBP.Documents.RWS;component/Resources/ThirdPartyDocumentResourceDictionary.xaml"
```

Or may be you could offer more elegant solution?